# Why does printing a pointer print the same thing as printing the dereferenced pointer?

Tags: pointers, rust, dereference

From the Rust guide:

> To dereference (get the value being referred to rather than the reference itself) `y`, we use the asterisk (`*`)

So I did it:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 1;
    let ptr_y = &x;
    println!("x: {}, ptr_y: {}", x, *ptr_y);
}
```

This gives me the same results (x=1; y=1) even without an explicit dereference:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 1;
    let ptr_y = &x;
    println!("x: {}, ptr_y: {}", x, ptr_y);
}
```

Why? Shouldn't `ptr_y` print the memory address and `*ptr_y` print 1? Is there some kind of auto-dereference or did I miss something?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Rust usually focuses on object value (i.e. the interesting part of the contents) rather than object identity (memory addresses). The [implementation of `Display`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.18.0/src/libcore/fmt/mod.rs#L1470-L1485) for `&T` where `T` implements `Display` defers directly to the contents. Expanding that macro manually for the `String` implementation of `Display`:

```
impl<'a> Display for &'a String {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result {
        Display::fmt(&**self, f)
    }
}
```

That is, it is just printing its contents directly.

If you care about object identity/the memory address, you can use the [`Pointer` formatter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Pointer.html), `{:p}`:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 1;
    let ptr_y = &x;
    println!("x: {}, ptr_y: {}, address: {:p}", x, ptr_y, ptr_y);
}
```

Output:

```
x: 1, ptr_y: 1, address: 0x7fff4eda6a24
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e82055a3b0a0b2aa8bf01c2154f2d294&version=stable)

Comment: I read at the Rust guide about pointers a bit after your posting and they just use "{:p}, ptr_y" because "println! will automatically dereference it for us".

A short question:
I usually use something like "Type name = value" or "int test = 1". It seems I can't have that in Rust as an option, "let int test = 1" gives compiler error? I know the compiler gets the type automatically but for the sake of my syntax I would like to write it in my code when declaring :(.

Anyway, thanks for your answer even when I have no clue what the macro is doing exactly :).

Comment: Oh, yes,`{:p}` also works, the `p` [format specifier](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fmt/#formatting-traits) is [implemented for various kinds of pointers](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fmt/trait.Pointer.html) to just print the address.

Comment: [Types are specified as `let x: Type = 1;`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/guide.html#variable-bindings).

Answer (score 8):

```
fn main() {
 let x = &42;
 let address = format!("{:p}", x); // this produces something like '0x7f06092ac6d0'
 println!("{}", address);
}
```