# Not understanding how to access the elements of a vector in Rust

Tags: pointers, vector, reference, rust

This is my first encounter with Rust, and I am reading the chapter on vectors in the current version of the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-01-vectors.html). I do have previous experience with other languages (mostly functional ones, where the following issues are hidden).

Running the following code snippet (from the book) returns `3`:

```
fn main() {
  let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  let third: &i32 = &v[2];
  println!("{}", third);
}
```

1. The first thing that I do not understand is why the `third` inside the `println!` macro isn't referenced. I would have expected the above code to print the memory address of the 3rd element of `v` (as in C and C++), not its content.

Consider now the code (notice the reference this time inside `println!`):

```
fn main() {
  let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  let third: &i32 = &v[2];
  println!("{}", *third);
}
```

2. Why does the code code above produce exactly the same output as the one above it, as if the `*` made no difference?

Finally, let us rewrite the above code snippets eliminating references completely:

```
fn main() {
  let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  let third: i32 = v[2];
  println!("{}", third);
}
```

3. Why does this last version produce the same output as the previous two? And what type does `v[2]` really have: is it an `&i32` or an `i32`?

Are all of the above a manifestation of the automatic dereferencing that is only once alluded to in a previous chapter? (If so, then the book should be rewritten, because it is more confusing than clarifying.)

Comment: If you want to know the type you can specify `()` as the type and study the error message, i.e. `let third: () = v[2];`.

Comment: possible dulication of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852613/why-does-printing-a-pointer-print-the-same-thing-as-printing-the-dereferenced-po ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: *I'm learning Rust too, so please take this with a grain of salt.*

To understand what happens, it might be easier with [cargo-expand](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand).

For the code

```
fn main() {
  let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  let third: &i32 = &v[2];
  println!("{}", third);
}
```

we get (I've removed irrelevant codes)

```
fn main() {
    ...
    let third: ...
    {
        ::io::_print(::std::fmt::Arguments::new_v1_formatted(                            
            ...
            &match (&third,) {                                                           
                (arg0,) => [::std::fmt::ArgumentV1::new(arg0, ::std::fmt::Display::fmt)],
            },
            ...
        ));
    };
}
```

for the first/last case, and

```
fn main() {
    ...
    let third: ...
    {
        ::io::_print(::std::fmt::Arguments::new_v1_formatted(                            
            ...
            &match (&*third,) {                                                           
                (arg0,) => [::std::fmt::ArgumentV1::new(arg0, ::std::fmt::Display::fmt)],
            },
            ...
        ));
    };
}
```

for the second case.

Which, roughly, means that, for `{}` formatter, the function `fmt` (of the trait `Display`) will be called for a reference to `third` or `*third` respectively.

Let's apply this logic for

- second case: `third: &i32` then `*third: i32`, this is where [`impl Display for i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html#impl-Display-14) applies.
- first case: `third: &i32`, this works also because of [`impl<'_, T> Display for &'_ T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html#impl-Display-72) (where `T` is `i32`)
- last case: `third: i32`: is the same as the first case. Moreover, `v[2]` (which is of type `i32`) works because [impl Index for Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Index%3CI%3E) (note that: `let third = v[2]` works because [impl Copy for i32](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#impl-Copy), i.e copy semantics is applied for `=` instead of the default move semantics).