# How does println! interact with multiple levels of indirection?

Tags: pointers, rust

I have the following program:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 0;

    println!("Example 1: {:p}", &x);
    println!("Example 1: {:p}", &x);

    println!("Example 2: {:p}", &&x);
    println!("Example 2: {:p}", &&x);
}
```

Here is an example output:

```
Example 1: 0x7ffcb4e72144
Example 1: 0x7ffcb4e72144
Example 2: 0x7ffcb4e72238
Example 2: 0x7ffcb4e72290
```

The outputs for `"Example 1"` are consistently the same, while those for `"Example 2"` are consistently different.

I've read [Does println! borrow or own the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450399/does-println-borrow-or-own-the-variable), and what I understood from the given answer is that `println!` takes a reference silently. In other words, this sounds like `println!` adds an extra level of indirection.

I had expected the outputs for `"Example 1"` to be different as well. Seeing that `println!` silently takes another level of indirection, `"Example 1"` is actually working with `&&x`, and `"Example 2"` is working with `&&&x`. This seems to agree with the answer I linked, specifically: `"If you write println!("{}", &x), you are then dealing with two levels of references"`.

I thought that the value `&&x` holds would be printed for `"Example 1"`, while the value `&&&x` holds would be printed for `"Example 2"`. Both `&&x` and `&&&x` hold a temporary `&x`, so I thought `"Example 1"` would have different addresses printed as well.

Where am I wrong? Why doesn't `"Example 1"` have different addresses printed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does printing a pointer print the same thing as printing the dereferenced pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852613/why-does-printing-a-pointer-print-the-same-thing-as-printing-the-dereferenced-po)

Comment: why address of x should change ? `&&x` is the address of the address of `x`, as you create this variable temporary, two literals `&&x` value equality is unspecified. println only borrow for non copy type, all reference can be copied so they are not borrow by println.

Comment: @SCappella I don't think so, because answer for that question involves behavior of `Display` which applies to `{}` and not `{:p}`.

Comment: @Stargateur My understanding is that `println!` borrows regardless of whether it's a non-copy type or not. For example, answer of the question I linked has at the bottom: `If you write println!("{}", &x), you are then dealing with two levels of references`. Sounds like extra level of indirection is applied even to references of `x`.

Comment: @MarioIshac well, anyway you ask println to print the value of &x, so even if the macro take a &&x, it will show what you ask so &x, doesn't really matter if there is two level of indirection (and I'm pretty sure final asm would get rid of it). What you need to understand is that `&x` is very different of `&&x`.

Comment: @Stargateur yup sounds like that's what's going on, but I'm wondering how? if macro receives `&&x` then how does it get treated as `&x`?

Comment: as documented, `println!("{:p}", &x)` will print the address of `x`. what it does under the hood is irrelevant, even if it used 5 levels of indirection, it will still print the address of `x` because thats what its supposed to do. if it handles `&x` by reference, `&&x`, then all it needs is a deref, `*`, to get it back for final printing. its not complicated. the only way the first two prints could differ is if `x` moved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's start with a trick question: Does this compile or not?

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:p}", 1i32);
}
```

We're asking to print an `i32` as a memory address. Does this make sense?

No, of course, and Rust rightfully rejects this program.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `i32: std::fmt::Pointer` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:2:22
  |
2 |     println!("{:p}", 1i32);
  |                      ^^^^ the trait `std::fmt::Pointer` is not implemented for `i32`
  |
  = note: required by `std::fmt::Pointer::fmt`
  = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

But we know that the macro implicitly borrow the arguments, so `1i32` becomes `&1i32`. And references *do* implement `Pointer`. So what's the deal?

First, it helps to understand *why* the macro borrows its arguments. Have you ever noticed that [all the formatting traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html#traits) look virtually identical? They all define exactly one method, named `fmt`, that takes two parameters, `&self` and a `&mut Formatter` and returns `Result<(), fmt::Error>`.

It is the `&self` that is relevant here. In order to call `fmt`, we only need a reference to the value, because formatting a value doesn't need ownership of that value. Now, the implementation of formatting arguments is more complicated than this, but ultimately, for an argument `x`, the program would end up calling `std::fmt::Pointer::fmt(&x, formatter)` (for `:p`). However, for this call to compile successfully, the type of `x` must implement `Pointer`, *not* the type of `&x`. If `x` is `1i32`, then the type of `x` is `i32`, and `i32` doesn't implement `Pointer`.

The conclusion is that the `:p` format will end up printing the value of the pointer represented by the expression written textually in your program. The borrow taken on that expression is there so that the macro doesn't take ownership of the argument (which is still useful for `:p`, e.g. if you wanted to print a `Box<T>`).

---

Now we can proceed to explaining the behavior of your program. `x` is a local variable. Local variables usually<sup>1</sup> have a stable address<sup>2</sup>. In your `Example 1` calls, the expression `&x` allows us to observe that address. Both occurrences of `&x` will give the same result because `x` hasn't moved between the calls. What's printed is the address of `x` (i.e. the address that holds the value `0`).

However, the expression `&&x` is a bit curious. What does it mean exactly to take the address twice? The subexpression `&x` produces a temporary value, because the result is not assigned to a variable. Then, we ask the address of that temporary value. [Rust is kind enough to let us do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253/234590), but that means we must store the temporary value somewhere in memory in order for it to have *some* address. Here, the temporary value is stored in some hidden local variable.

It turns out that in debug builds, the compiler creates a separate hidden variable for each of the `&x` subexpressions in the two occurrences of `&&x`. That's why we can observe two different memory addresses for the `Example 2` lines. However, [in release builds](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=5ccd59dff39f8f99b1e7e618e2b5a219), the code is optimized so that only one hidden variable is created (because at the point where we need the second one, we no longer need the first one, so we can reuse its memory location), so the two `Example 2` lines actually print the same memory address!

---

<sup>1</sup> I say *usually* because there might be situations where an optimizer could decide to move a local variable around in memory. I don't know if any optimizer actually does that in practice.

<sup>2</sup> Some local variables might not have an "address" at all! An optimizer may decide to keep a local variable in a register instead if the address of that variable is never observed. On many processor architectures, registers cannot be addressed by a pointer, because they live in a different "address space", so to speak. Of course, here, we *are* observing the address, so we can be pretty confident that the variable actually lives on the stack.

Comment: This is a beyond great answer! Since `std::fmt::Pointer::fmt` takes a reference to an implementer of `Pointer`, sounds like it will do some dereferencing internally to remove the extra level of indirection introduced by borrowing instead of owning (so it can print the hexadecimal-formatted value of the implementer of `Pointer` instead of the reference one level up). Is that a right way to think about it?