# Writing to a reference updates the underlying value but the reference prints unexpected value

Tags: rust

```
use std::io::Write;
fn main() {
    let mut x = [0u8; 10];
    let mut y = &mut x[..];
    y.write(b"1");
    y.write(b".");
    println!("{:p}", y);
    println!("{:?}", y);
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

I get the following output

```
0x7ffeddab2b8a
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[49, 46, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I thought that `println!("{:?}", y);` should have printed the address value or the value of the underlying data. But it does not do anything out of those 2 options. (reading from this answer on stack overflow - [Why does printing a pointer print the same thing as printing the dereferenced pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852613/why-does-printing-a-pointer-print-the-same-thing-as-printing-the-dereferenced-po)  I thought it should have printed the value of x ie `[49, 46, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`  )

My questions are

1. When we print the y using the print statement what is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` referring to ?
2. How do I print the value of the underlying value of y (using y only.)?
3. Can someone explain why it prints `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is using the implementation of `std::io::Write` for `&mut [u8]`. When you write `y.write(...)`, you're calling the `write` method, which takes `&mut self`, i.e., `write` receives a mutable reference to `y`. In order for each `write` call not to overwrite each other, `write` *mutates* the slice by removing the range that was just written to from the head of the slice. After writing *n* bytes to the slice, the slice's data pointer is incremented by *n* and the slice's length is decremented by *n*.

> 1. When we print the y using the print statement what is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` referring to ?
> 2. Can someone explain why it prints `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

It's referring to the remaining space in your buffer. Notice that there are only 8 zeroes, because you wrote 2 bytes in a 10-byte buffer.

> 2. How do I print the value of the underlying value of y (using y only.)?

The data you wrote in the buffer cannot be accessed through `y`, because `y` points to the rest of the buffer.

In order to get a slice of the data that was written to the buffer, you need to write something like this:

```
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut x = [0u8; 10];
    let mut y = &mut x[..];
    y.write(b"1");
    y.write(b".");

    let y_len = y.len();
    let len = x.len() - y_len;
    println!("{:?}", &x[0..len]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. It's referring to the part of `x` that is not yet written to (see 3 for a detailed explanation)
2. Debug print is the way to go here, but using the slice with the write isn't. You can either print `x` or have another slice (be careful with the borrow checker here!)
3. `println!("{:?}", y);` is called a **debug print**, which is
   basically using the Debug trait, which prints the slice in this case.
   The reason why you see eight zeros is because using `write` on a slice will cause the slice to point to the yet-unwritten part. You are writing twice, and that's why there are eight zeros. See here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-Write-for-%26mut+%5Bu8%5D